# Ruby on Rails ---sql query for records of a specific user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails and would appreciate any help.
This application is meant to help students get the results of their sql query. So I'm expecting input of sql from the students.
I'm trying to "select * from posts where uid <4" for a specific Student. That is , he can only see certain tuples with his student_id. And the application controller is as follows(where current user is the login information of this student):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.



  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :ensure_login
  helper_method :logged_in?, :current_user

  def index

  end



  protected
    def ensure_login
      # Always go to login page unless session contains
      # reviewer_id
      redirect_to login_path unless session[:student_id]
    end

    def logged_in?
      session[:student_id] # nil is false
    end

    def current_user
      @current_user ||= Student.find(session[:student_id])
    end


end
```

In the corresponding controller, i wrote something like this ,trying to only find the current_user's records but it failed(it gives all the tuples with uid <4 no matter what's the student_id) :

```
def findit

    #render json: { success: "It works", operator: params[:operator].inspect,condition: params[:condition].inspect,table: params[:table].inspect}

    @results = current_user.posts.find_by_sql(params[:sql])
    render json: { html: render_to_string(:template => 'all/findit') }
    #render json: { c: @columns}

  end
```

But the following code in posts_controller.rb works. It only has the records for this specific student. So what's wrong for findit?

```
 def index
    @posts = current_user.posts.all
  end
```

The schema is:(And there's a session model too)

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20200325201224) do

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "title"
    t.text    "content"
    t.integer "uid"
    t.integer "student_id"
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "year"
    t.integer "uid"
    t.integer "student_id"
  end

end
```

Thank you so much for helping!!!!

Comment: I don't really know where to start here as there are so many things that are off. 1. Don't put actions in your ApplicationController as it the superclass of all your controllers so you're adding an index method to all your controllers. 2. Why on earth are you using `find_by_sql` with user input? Thats the biggest SQL injection vulnerablity I have ever seen.

Comment: This is not really salvagable. Can you describe the real world problem this code is supposed to solve instead?

Comment: Thanks for helping and i just edited with more information.

Answer (score 0):

`def current_user
      @current_user ||= Student.find(session[:student_id])
  end`

Thats incorrect your getting the student not the user

do this

`def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:student_id])
  end`

because the user has the uid and there are no relations to do something like student.user.uid

To find the post then do this 
`Post.where(uid: @current_user.uid)`

Comment: Hey, just a tip you can use ``` (three backticks) to create code blocks in your posts. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code